# NHibernate Batch Size across entire app - any problems?

Tags: nhibernate, batch-file

If I configure NHibernate with a batch size of say 20, am I likely to run into problems in regular, non-batch-update related scenarios?

The majority of updates/inserts performed by my application are once-offs. But in certain cases I am doing large scale updates/inserts which would benefit from batching. Should I use a different session configuration for these, or do you think I can safely leave the batch size higher for the entire app?

The reason I ask is that it is hassle to setup a different session just for the batching scenarios (because this is a web app with per-request sessions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [NH documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-batch-updates), the only negative to batch updates that is mentioned is this:

> optimistic concurrency checking may be
> impaired since ADO.NET 2.0 does not
> return the number of rows affected by
> each statement in the batch, only the
> total number of rows affected by the
> batch.

And I would not think that would be a problem for small batches. So I doubt that a higher batch size will negatively affect your application's normal functioning.

*However*, you should consider creating a new session for your batch operations anyway. A normal NHibernate session is going to be [inefficient for batch updates/inserts](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-inserts), because the first-level cache tracks every single object. You can control this manually by doing `session.Flush(); session.Clear();` regularly, but it is probably easier to use a StatelessSession instead.